# Dynamic Model (non-class) Metadata Provider in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are developing an application where the end-user schema is dynamic (we have a good business case for this - it is not something that can be handled easily by a static model).

I have used the .NET DynamicObject class to allow these dynamic schema objects to be addressed easily from code, and expected this to just work with the MVC model metadata. However the MVC metadata support seems to be hamstrung in that it only deals with meta-data defined per type - not per object which will be the case here.

Even when I dug down and tried implementing our own ModelMetadataProvider, it seems that the neccessary information is simply not passing in - the GetMetadataForProperty method is particularly problematic. Effectively I need to access the parent or container object for the property, but all that is passed in is the type.

The above is called mainly from the FromStringExpression method in the ModelMetadata class. This method actually DOES have the container (at least in this case) but does not pass it through. This branch is executed when it finds the view data about the expression stored (cached?) in the ViewData. If that fails it falls back to looking it up via the ModelMetadata object - which ironically might work for me. Whats particularly irritating is that the FromStringExpression method is static, so I can't easily override its behavior.

In desperation I have considered trying to traverse the modelAccessor expression, but this seems like a kludge at best and extremely fragile.

I have searched extensively for a solution to this. Many point to Brad Wilson's talk (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Brad-Wilson-Advanced-MVC-3) on non-class models, however if you look at the actual code presented, you will see that it TOO is bound to the TYPE and not the object - in other words not terribly useful. Others have pointed to the http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/, but that only seems to apply to the validation side, and I suspect suffers from the same problem (bound to type rather than object) as the above.

For example, I may have a dictionary object that contains a series of field objects. This looks something like (very cut down/simplified example):

```
public class Entity : DynamicObject, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, EntityProp> Props { get; set; }

    ... DynamicObject and ICustomTypeDescriptor implementation to expose Props as dynamic properties against this Entity ...
}

public class EntityProp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

This might be passed to a view as its view-mode (or part of it), and in my view I'd like to use:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Has anyone found a way around this?

I've identified two possible alternative approaches, but both have significant drawbacks:

- Abandon using the MVC ModelMetadata for this, and instead build a view-model that directly contains the necessary metadata, along with the templates needed to display these more complex view-model objects. Means however that I'm then having to treat these objects differently to 'normal' objects, defeating the purpose somewhat and increasing the amount of view templates we need to build. **This is the approach I am leaning towards now - more or less abandoning integrating with the MVC ModelMetadata stuff**
- Generate a unique key for each templated property, and use this for the property name rather than the display name - that would allow the ModelMetadataProvider to find the metadata that related to the property without needing a reference to its parent. However this would lead to a fairly ugly situation when debugging, and again seems like a large scale kludge. *I have now tried a simplified version of this, and it seems to work, but does have some undesirable behavior, such as needing to use an meaningless property name if I want to explicitly bind to elements of the model.*
- In the ModelMetadataProvider when returning a collection of ModelMetadata objects for contained properties, record the container in the ModelMetadataProvider that is associated with those returned properties. *I have tried this, but this returned collection of property metadata is ignored in this case, and the FromStringExpression method goes directly to the GetMetadataForProperty method instead.*

Comment: MVC is open source.. you could investigate replacing the ModelMetadata functionality with your own code.

Comment: I have actually looked at that. The problem is that in the MVC source relating to ModelMetaDataProvider, the actual public methods that I would be overriding/replacing are not passed the necessary information (i.e. the container object) to actually find and return the related metadata.

Comment: Just to be clear - the GetMetadataForProperty method gets passed the TYPE of the container, but not the container itself. Hence if the meta-data varies based on the container (and not just its type), you don't have enough information to find it.

Comment: And so, being open-source you can find where that method is called and add the correct data to the function call.

Comment: Not keen on using a modified version of the MVC source in our project. This is no toy project, and modifying the MVC source would result in a maintenance headache. Will amend question to include details on the problematic bit in MVC which cannot easily be overridden.

Comment: Fair enough.  Are you using any data from ModelMetadata that can't be gotten via reflection?

Comment: No - reflection should be fine. But that would mean all the standard MVC templates (plus third party ones) would have to be amended. Frankly that's what I'm looking at now (although using the type descriptor or our internal metadata objects directly rather than reflection). Just seem to loose a lot of the value of MVC that way.

Comment: Thinking this is actually a flaw in MVC's design (admittedly one which probably doesn't affect many people) - will have to see about reporting it.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  The ModelMetadata can be partially filled from data annotations.. and since you can only annotate a class (type), not an object, it kinda makes sense.  Also, using dynamicobject as your model is really an abuse of MVC in .NET (a strongly typed framework) where the model is expected to be strongly typed.  I would agree it would seem like a flaw in a framework that was based on duck typing.  .NET's duck typing (dynamicobject) came late in the game and is really only meant as a bridge to dynamic languages like python.

Comment: Not dissin on your project - just don't agree with your assessment that its a flaw in the design.  You would have to extend the flaw status all the way to the underlying framework.

Comment: The DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider (attributes bound to class) is just one of the available metadata providers. My issue is the framework does not offer the opportunity to drive one from anything other than the type; I can't see how this would be of any real value when using most non-class models. Just wish the material I'd read on this had been clearer on that point - a lot of it seemed to imply that this was exactly what custom ModelMetadataProviders were there for. Looks like its back to the drawing board and a more complex view model with all custom templates.

Comment: what about this `modelAccessor` parameter of `GetMetaDataForProperty` ?

Comment: That is an accessor for the value (e.g. <some EntityProp>.Value). The metadata is one level above that (the container). I have considered traversing the expression, but that's certainly a kludge and possibly very fragile.

Comment: First of all, EditorForModel can only work with type. How can it distinguish editor by instance? We are using dynamic model but we are not using any of EditorForModel or similar methods because our web app is JavaScript app, and controller only processes json requests. JavaScript app manages which editor to load but everything is done on browser. You need to outline me complete use case for us to point you in some direction.

Comment: For dynamic properties serialization, have a look at http://entityrestsdk.codeplex.com, it might help you in solving same problem little differently.

Comment: Akash; this is exactly my point. It CANNOT distinguish by instance. In our case the meta-data IS defined by instance (more or less). I had a loot at Entity REST. We would like to keep the client code as thin as possible, which means using views on the server to build the UI (we are better .NET coders than Javascript coders).  Entity REST seems to just provide a set of consistent AJAX services delivering JSON.

Comment: Entity REST SDK is not only for AJAX, but it works well with your other ASP.NET MVC controllers as well. We have created AtomEntity which implements ICustomTypeDescriptor and it dynamically hides properties based on instance itself.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've worked around this issue by reflecting into `modelAccessor` and grabbing the values it's captured, and it's worked well for me. I just had to accept that I'll need to be very careful if we ever change the framework version. I do think that this is a flaw in the (generally excellent) design of the MVC framework - it significantly restricts the flexibility of the metadata system for very little gain.

Comment: So its NOT just me then. That's a relief.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for obtaining the object that that property being called belongs to - for generating the model metadata based off of the object, and not the class? I had a similar problem, and had created a custom ModelMetadataProvider by digging through the modelAccessor, but as you said, it was fragile, and broke when I tried to add a second custom model using inheritance and letting the code fall through to a lower one when it was not a type it was designed to handle. This was because now the actual object I wanted is two levels up, not just one.

Comment: No. In the end we went with a completely different approach and suspended the project based on the EAV models.

Comment: @LinusDillon what was your different approach?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe creating a custom ModelMetadataProvider:

```
public class CustomViewModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{

    public override IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> GetMetadataForProperties(object container, Type containerType)
    {
        if (containerType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("containerType");
        }

        return GetMetadataForPropertiesImpl(container, containerType);
    }

    private IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> GetMetadataForPropertiesImpl(object container, Type containerType)
    {
        var propertiesMetadata = new List<ModelMetadata>();
        foreach (EntityProp eprop in ((Entity)container).Props.Values)
        {
            Func<object> modelAccessor = () => eprop;
            propertiesMetadata.add(GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, eprop.Name));
        }
        return propertiesMetadata;  // List returned instead of yielding, hoping not be needed to re-call this method more than once
    }

    public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, string propertyName) {
        if (containerType == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("containerType");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "propertyName");
        }

        return CreateMetadata(null, containerType, modelAccessor, modelAccessor().Type, propertyName);
    }

    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        EntityProp eprop = modelAccessor();
        DataAnnotationsModelMetadata result;
        if (propertyName == null)
        {
            // You have the main object
            return base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            // You have here the property object
            result = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadata(this, containerType, () => eprop.Value, modelType, propertyName, null);
            result.IsRequired = eprop.IsRequired;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally, setup your custom provider in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomViewModelMetadataProvider();
}
```

Comment: As I stated, I have looked (extensivly) at writing our own ModelMetadataProvider. The problem is that it does not get passed the information it needs to do what I want (i.e. it does not get passed the container model, only an accessor to the property value). This means that at best, I can define meta-data per class rather than per object as I need to do in this case.